# How to merge two models with one-to-many relation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, rails-activerecord

I have two models, say `Author` and `Book`, where an `Author` has many `Book`s. I have to fetch through AJAX a list of `Author`s' names with their respective `Books`s names.

I have a few ideas, but don't really know which one is best.

1. Fetch them independently (all `Author`s and `Book`s and use filters to group them in JavaScript), but it seems like putting the work which should be done by the server on JavaScript.
2. Create a ruby class/struct which would contain an `Author` and an array of `Book`s. Query `Author`s and for each query the respective `Book`s, but this seems like unnecessarily many db queries.
3. Same as above but instead of a wrapper class get attributes' hash of `Author`s and insert arrays of attributes' hashes of `Book`s. Same problem as above with multiple queries.
4. Preferably join the tables somehow in one query to retrieve all of the `Author`s already merged with their `Book`s. Something like sql join but for one-to-many relation (if such even exists at all).

Comment: Have you already looked into `active_model_serializer`?

Comment: No, I haven't. I spent a lot of time googlong the question and this is the first time I heard this name. I will look into it now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Model Serializer is a quick and easy solution for this. It serializes your data as json as well as provides **full control over which attributes you want to show.**

In your gemfile:

```
gem 'active_model_serializers'
```

Then run the following commands:

```
bundle install
rails g serializer Author
rails g serializer Book
```

Now you will have 2 new files generated.

## author_serializer.rb

```
class AuthorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :id  
  # add your other author attributes here such as:
  # attribute :name
  # attribute :age
  has_many :books
end
```

## book_serializer.rb

```
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :id  
  # add your other book attributes here such as:
  # attribute :title
  # attribute :publisher
end
```

## authors_controller.rb

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render status: :ok, 
           json: Author.all, 
           each_serializer: AuthorSerializer
  end

  def show
    render status: :ok, 
           json: Author.find(params[:id]), 
           serializer: AuthorSerializer
  end
end
```

Notice the index specifies `each_serializer` and show specifies `serializer`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do

```
Author.includes(:books)
```

That will generate two queries, one for authors, one for books, and you will get a collection of 'author' objects, each with a collection of 'books'.

Answer (score 1):

To serialize the `Author`s and `Book`s to JSON, you can provide the `include` parameter to `to_json`:

```
class SomeJsonController < ApplicationController
  def show
    author = Author.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: author.to_json(include: :books) }
    end
  end
end
```

Full documentation is available [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json). `active_model_serializer` will also work (and will scale better if you're going to have a bunch of these kinds of cases where you need to render JSON for associations) but might be overkill if you just have the one case.